# Messages are not sent to the Flask-Mail

Tags: python, flask, gmail, flask-mail

I write a website on Flask, I decided to create a password recovery system via email, using Flask-Mail for this, everything seems to work, there are no errors, it redirects to the authorization page, but there is no message in the mail

*There is my configs*

```
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.googlemail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 587
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = True
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = os.getenv('MAIL_USERNAME')
app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'] = os.getenv('MAIL_SENDER')
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = os.getenv('MAIL_PASSWORD')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = SECRET_KEY
```

*There is my userclass with methods that generate and verify the token*

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(65), nullable=False, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(60), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)

    def get_reset_password_token(self, expires_in=1800):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_in)
        return s.dumps({'user_id': self.id}).decode('utf-8')

    @staticmethod
    def verify_reset_password_token(token):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'])
        try:
            user_id = s.loads(token)['user_id']
        except Exception:
            return
        return User.query.get(user_id)
```

*this is my function that sends emails*

```
def send_password_reset_email(user):
    token = user.get_reset_password_token()
    msg = Message('Запит на зміну паролю', sender='ssaitlib123@gmail.com',
                  recipients=[user.email])
    msg.body = f"""
        Для того,щоб змінити свій пароль,натисніть на наступне посилання:
        {url_for('reset_password', token=token, _external=True)}
        Якщо ви не запитували зміну паролю,протсо забийте на це повідомлення
        """
    mail.send(msg)
```

*that is handler functions for password change pages*

```
@app.route('/reset_password_request', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def reset_password_request():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index_page'))
    form = ResetPasswordRequestForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=form.email.data).first()
        if user:
            send_password_reset_email(user)
        return redirect(url_for('login_page'))
    return render_template('reset_password_request.html', title='Відновлення паролю', form=form,
                           css_link=css_file_reset_password_request_page)


@app.route('/reset_password/<token>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def reset_password(token):
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    user = User.verify_reset_password_token(token)
    if not user:
        return redirect(url_for('index_page'))
    form = ResetPasswordForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit:
        user.set_password(form.password.data)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Пароль успішно змінений')
        return redirect(url_for('login_page'))
    return render_template('reset_password.html', form=form, title='Відновлення паролю',
                           css_file=css_file_authorization)
```

These two lines are executed successfully, without errors, but nothing comes to the e-mail

```
flash('Пароль успішно змінений')
return redirect(url_for('login_page'))
```

Help me please!

Comment: are you aware of this? https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: yes, I know, I'm using the app password, not the account, because otherwise I had an error